# Generalizing Hall's marriage theorem to non-perfect matchings

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory, perfect-matchings, bipartite-graphs

Let $G = (X, Y, E)$ be bipartite graph such that $|X|=|Y|=n$.

A *matching* $M \subseteq E$ is a subset of disjoint edges 
(i.e., there does not exist a pair of edges $(x, y) \in M$ and $(x', y') \in M$ such that $x = x'$ or $y = y'$).

Given a subset of vertices $S \subseteq X$, let $N(S)$ denotes the neighborhood of $S$ 
(i.e., the set of all vertices in $Y$ that are adjacent to at least one element of $S$).

Recall that $G$ admits a *perfect matching* (i.e., a perfect matching of size $n$) if and only if

$$|S| \leq |N(S)|$$
for all $S \subseteq X$, due to **Hall's Marriage Theorem**.

My question is whether there exists a generalization of this theorem for checking if $G$ admits a matching of size $k$ given a constant $k \leq n$ (instead of a perfect matching).

Comment: Yes: A bipartite graph $\left(G,X,Y\right)$ has a matching of size $\geq k$ if and only if $\left|S\right| \leq \left|N\left(S\right)\right| + \left|X\right| - k$ for every $S \subseteq X$. This is fairly well-known and should be in any text on matching theory. (Too lazy to find a real reference, but the hard direction -- meaning $\Longleftarrow$ -- follows from Theorem 8.4.7 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.04512v1 . Alternatively, you can also derive it from the usual Hall marriage theorem by introducing $\left|X\right| - k$ camp followers.)

Comment: As Darij says, this is well known and the usual “augmenting path” algorithm (which is a special case of the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm) finds a maximum size matching, in an efficient manner.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks! What do you mean by camp followers?

Comment: I mean that you can add $\left|X\right|-k$ new vertices to $Y$ and join them to every element of $X$.